# Highcharts solidgauge - repeatable div's - duplicate value in php variable

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have the following issue with highcharts SolidGauge.
Please find some context - SolidGauge is to be displayed for each comment that I call from MySql. Each comment brings in to PHP variable [$myvalue] a proprietary value per comment ID - [$myvalue] called outside of the Chart code, in the same file, works perfectly fine and shows distributed values correctly for each comment.

Issue - [$myvalue] shows duplicate value for each chart displayed in the UI - mor exactly the last comment value which is [8] - so all the Charts are showing value [8]. Please help :) I've tried everything (from unset, destroy etc)

```
$(function () {                                             
 $(document).ready(function () {            

// The speed gauge
$('.container-speed').each(function() {         
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {                                        
        type: 'solidgauge',
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
        renderTo: this
    },
    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '50%'],
        size: '65%',
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#f5f5f5',
            innerRadius: '90%',
            outerRadius: '80%',
            shape: 'circle'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: -15,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    },
     title: null,
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 8,
         stops: [
            [0.99, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [1.1, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [1.2, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
         lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 100,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 90,
            x: 30
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        data: [<?php echo $myvalue; ?>],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-size:14px;color:' +
                                                  ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'gray') + '"><?php echo $myvalue; ?></span></div>'
        }}] })      })                                                  
 })                                                                         
});
```

Comment: For me, works fine http://jsfiddle.net/3cmwLm8s/2/.

Comment: Works perfectly with the random math function -  thanks for the input - however the php loop (in Wordpress) has something in conflict because the variable assigned to DataSet returns always a single output (last comment ID) inside the JS script... I have to figure this out :)

Answer (score 0):

you should iterate over values, while invoking

```
$('.container-speed').each(function() //pass value in this function
```

pass value in this function and then call it in datalabels.

Comment: thanks for input - returns blank (no chart) $('.container-speed').each(function(<?php echo $myvalue ?>) and same as before with $('.container-speed').each(function(<?php $myvalue ?>)

Answer (score 0):

$( document ).ready(function() {
var gaugeOptions = {

```
    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
    },

    title: null,

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '50%'],
        size: '55%',
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 270,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#f5f5f5',
            innerRadius: '90%',
            outerRadius: '90%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [1.0, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [1.1, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [1.3, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 45,
        tickWidth: 1,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 90,
            x: 30
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: -15,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};

// My Container
$('#container_myContainer_<? echo $comment->comment_ID ?>').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 8
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        data: [<? echo get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'myValue', true )?>],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-size:14px;color:' +
                                                  ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'gray') + '"><? echo get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'myValue', true )?></span></div>'
        }
    }]

}))
```

})